# Is there a way to process a catch block without invalidating the current transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, try-catch, spatial

I have some TSQL that takes in WKT representations of geography and processes them.
Part of the processing is to check that they are valid bits of WKT before using them.
To do this I use the STIsValid() fucntion. When this function sees WKT with coordinates it considers are invalid it returns 0 (you can then make them valid with .MakeValid().

But, if it sees something that is clearly not WKT it throws an error, e.g.

```
geography::STGeomFromText('I_AM_NOT_WKT', 4326).STIsValid() = 0
```

Gives:

```
System.FormatException: 24114: The label I_AM_NOT_WKT in the input well-known text (WKT) is not valid.
```

Rather than try to write something that pre validates WKT to get it to a level that SQL can check, I decided to use a TRY CATCH block to get the records with bad WKT without crashing the routine. This  works fine. The problem is if I do that it invalidates the transaction I've got going.

This is the basic structure of my TSQL:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        …
        --Doing some stuff
        …
        TRY
            Is the current string valid WKT format (test using STIsValid())
            NO?
                Make the string valid using .MakeValid()
        END TRY
        CATCH
            --The string was not valid WKT format
            -- It's bad so write it to the bad table. !!! This causes the error !!!
        END CATCH
        …
        --doing more stuff
        …
    COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```

As soon as I get a bad WKT string to test the whole transaction is doomed and therefore as soon as I try to write to the bad table I get the error:

" The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file"

Which is to be expected.

My question is, is there a way to prevent the CATCH block invalidating my transaction? Or can anyone see another way around this?

Thanks

Comment: The `CATCH` is not invalidating the transaction. The symptoms suggest `SET XACT_ABORT ON;`, a best practice with explict T-SQL transactions.  You could add `SET XACT_ABORT OFF;` so that the transaction is not automatically rolled back. The downside is the transaction could remain open in the case of a client timeout, so the client code will need to catch the error and execute `IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;` to clean up in a timely manner. Otherwise, the transaction will remain open until the pooled connection is reused or closed after inactivity.

Comment: Yes, don't let the exception get thrown in the first place, but leave `XACT_ABORT ON`. Code around the error.

Comment: Consider performing the validation before the `BEGIN TRAN` to avoid the rollback.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose, reading your answers and thinking about this more, I need to find a way to perform the validation without it throwing an error. My question should probably have been how I can get STIsValid() to not throw an error when it is passed something that is not WKT format. I think I need to code something that first detects basic WKT format rules then I can pass that to STIsValid for the actual geometry check.Thanks for your help.